# Passing URL parameter to link on page

Tags: url, get

I am trying to grab a parameter from a webpage and insert it into a URL link on that same page but am having problems with the syntax.

So, for example, the webpage is www.website.com?src=mm

Currently the code on the page that does not pull in the parameter is

```
<?php echo "<A HREF='http://www.website2.com?offer=AAt&sub1=422'><B>Click Here</B></A><BR>" ?>
```

I would like to include that "mm" parameter at the end of the URL so the final URL is:

```
http://www.website2.com?offer=AA&sub1=422&sub2=mm
```

I tried the following but does not work:

```
<?php echo "<A HREF='http://www.website2.com?offer=AA&sub1=422&sub2='.$_GET['src']."><B>Click Here</B></A><BR>" ?>
```

Any ideas on how to get this to work? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't even compile:

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'http' (T_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in /var/www/html/ImagePT/test.php on line 1
```

it has to be

```
<?php echo '<A HREF="http://www.website2.com?offer=AA&sub1=422&sub2='.$_GET['src'].'"><B>Click Here</B></A><BR>'; ?>
```

but since I'm just in the mood to give you some further advice:

You don't have to write HTML in uppercase, it's rather unusual (not impossible, but you don't see it very often) - then this script is horrible, when the `$_GET['src']` variable is undefinied, therefore I'd check if it is set and then modifiy the URL accordingly. So my advice would be to use the following:

```
<?php

    if(isset($_GET['src']))
    {
        echo '<a href="http://www.website2.com?offer=AA&sub1=422&sub2='.$_GET['src'].'"><b>Click Here</b></a></br>'; 
    }
    else
    {
        echo '<a href="http://www.website2.com?offer=AA&sub1=422"><b>Click Here</b></a></br>'; 
    }

?>
```